# Как вывести все элементы очереди?

Tags: c++, c, динамические-структуры

Всем привет. Создал очередь , как вывести первый элемент понял.
А как вывести все элементы?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
struct Queue
{
    int size;
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
};
void Creation(Queue* Q)
{
    Q->first = new Node; // выдялем память под новый элемент:
    Q->first->next = NULL;
    Q->last = Q->first;
    Q->size = 0;
}
void Add(Queue* Q)
{
    int value;
    cout << "Value";
    cin >> value;
    Q->last->next = new Node;
    Q->last = Q->last->next;
    Q->last->data = value;
    Q->last->next = NULL; // обнуление указателя на след.элемент
    Q->size++;
}
int top(Queue* Q)
{
    return Q->last->next->data;
}
bool Full(Queue* Q)
{
    if (Q->first == Q->last) return true;
    else return false;
}
int main()
{
    Queue Q;
    Creation(&Q);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Add(&Q);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе - примерно так:

```
void Print(Queue* Q)
{
    Node * n = Q->first;
    while(n)
    {
        cout << n->data << "  ";
        n = n->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Но вы ухитряетесь в `first` хранит указатель не на реальные данные, а на какой-то элемент с мусором. Исправьте эту ошибку.

Далее, у вас какая-то странная проверка "заполненности" (что это вообще такое - **полная** очередь?) в `Full`. Может, пустоты?

И последнее - это - не С++. Это голый С с выводом в `cout`. Но не С++. Именно поэтому я в вашем же стиле написал `Print`...